# Practical limits of Cedar's Ephemeral Filesystem on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

Can anyone provide insight into the practical limits in terms of the number of files and maximum size of dyno created files (individually and in total) a Cedar based Heroku application can support.

Answer (score 8):

Contacted Heroku support.

They claim there are no hard limits on number of files or size of files stored on the ephmeral filesystem.

In practice, if a dyno uses up the available RAM and / or CPU resources managing the files, the dyno will be killed and restarted which will effectively destroy the files.

Answer (score 0):

I've never run into a problem with any of my apps but they say slug size should be less than 200Mb, details [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size). You can't write any files to the filesystem except tmp which isn't guaranteed to be shared between your dynos so you have to write it out to Amazon S3 or such like.

Don't forget though, uploading a file will consume a dyno whilst the upload is taking place

Comment: According to the documentation on Cedar (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem#cedar), the /tmp restriction has been relaxed. I was wondering what the practical limits of writing to local ephemeral filesystem are.